# Instantly get input[type="file"] value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a website where i need to get a PDF, JPG or PNG from a user.
When the user choose a file i want the name of the file to be shown.
Furthermore I want to check if the file is a PDF, JPG or PNG instantly so the file cant be uploaded if it isn't such a file.

My code:

```
<style>
#file { display:none; }
</style>

<label for="file">  
    <div id="file-wrapper">  
        <input id="file" type="file" name="file" required/>
        <div class="button smallbtn">Choose file</div>
        <div id="filev">No file chosen</div>
    </div>
    </label>

    <script>   
       setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById("filev").innerHTML = document.getElementById("file").value;
        }, 2000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps!

```js
var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".pdf", ".png"];

function ValidateInput(oInput) {
  if (oInput.type == "file") {
    var sFileName = oInput.value;
    if (sFileName.length > 0) {
      var blnValid = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
        var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
        if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
          blnValid = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (!blnValid) {
        alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
        oInput.value = "";
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<style>
  #file {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<label for="file">  
    <div id="file-wrapper">  
        <input id="file" type="file" name="file" onChange="ValidateInput(this);" />
        <div class="button smallbtn">Choose file</div>
        <div id="filev">No file chosen</div>
    </div>
    </label>
```